# asp.net core razor pages - policy authorization - control access for organizations to folders pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a project with several applications, each contained in a specific folder in /Pages. /Pages/PTW, /Page/JM and so on. I already implemented User authentication and Role management for each page. I want to implement policy authorization for Companies so specific company users to have access to pages from a specific folder and I tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using RoSafety.Models;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RoSafety.Data;

public class AccessCodeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string AccessCode { get; set; }
    public AccessCodeRequirement(string accessCode)
    {
        AccessCode = accessCode;
    }
}

public class AccessCodeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessCodeRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   AccessCodeRequirement requirement)
    {

        var userId = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var orgID = _context.UsersData.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Select(x => x.OrgID).FirstOrDefault();
        var orgAccess = _context.CompanyAccesses.Select(x => x.AccessCode).ToList();

        foreach(var a in orgAccess)
        {
            var access = a;
            if(access == requirement.AccessCode)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In the startup I added

```
options.AddPolicy("PTW", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new AccessCodeRequirement("RO-01")));
```

and on the page I have

```
[Authorize(Policy = "PTW")]
```

The AccessCode for an OrgID in CompanyAccesses table is "RO-01" but I still have Access denied. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,your `_context` in your `AccessCodeHandler` is failed to inject.You should change your `AccessCodeHandler` like following.

```
 public class AccessCodeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessCodeRequirement>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    //add following code
    public AccessCodeHandler(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    //.....
}
```

Then in your `startup`,you should add service.

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("PTW", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new AccessCodeRequirement("RO-01")));
        });
 //add this code.
 services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, AccessCodeHandler>();
```